# Freemarker, looping sequence with one object/multiple attributes

Tags: freemarker

I am working on looping through one object with multiple attributes. In my scenario, I am looking for external content values.

| email_address | article01 | article02 | article03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email@address.com | Y |  | Y |

These values can change all the time, so we have to define them manually every instance where we use this, but I want to be able to list them in a sequence and then loop through and include them when object.attribute=Y.

The below block is purely conceptual, but referencing the attribute within the expression is where I get confused.

```
<#assign seq = ['article01','article02','article03']>
<#list seq as articles>
    <#if base.${article}="Y">
        <#include "*/${article}.htm"/>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

In this instance, the resulting code would be:

```html
<html><article01.html content></html>
<html><article03.html content></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `base.articel01` would work, you can use `base[article]` (instead of `base.${article}`).